# How to add Tag in URL using jquery

Tags: jquery, url

This is my URL.

```
localhost/baithe-Baithe-new/beta/venue-detail.html
```

I want this

```
localhost/baithe-Baithe-new/beta/venue-detail.html/Videos
```

when i click on videos tab. similarly If i will click on Features Tab then URL should be like this

```
localhost/baithe-Baithe-new/beta/venue-detail.html/Featurs
```

Does Any help me ? I want to achieve this using Jquery.

Comment: You cannot change the URL without reloading. So EITHER change the hash (#features) or interrogate the url when the page loads. BOTH have hundreds of examples here

Comment: Is this possible with page load?

Comment: Yes - but you have to show a [mcve] for use to show how. We need to see the HTML

Answer (score -1):

You can use this script to change url when you click on video button

```
<script>
// onclick event is assigned to the #button element.
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
  window.location.href = "localhost/baithe-Baithe-new/beta/venue-detail.html/Videos ";
};
</script>
```

Comment: i did, this will create URL localhost/baithe-Baithe-new/beta/venue-detail.html/Videos but not showing anything. Gives error 404 Not Found